# HTML grid layout with several columns using 100% height/width of the browser window

Tags: css, html

I want do divide entire html page to 4 sections
I use css :

```
 <style>
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.one {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1  ;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.two {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 2 ;
  grid-row: 1 ;
}
.three {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: violet;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.four {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: aqua;
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}
}
</style>
```

using this grid definition I define:

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="one" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="three" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="four" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But instead of creating 4 vertical sections, 4 horizontals are created and only part of html web is utilized. 
How should I change my code to work as expected?

**UPD**

After the change of div class to be `wrapper`:

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assigned class "column" to the wrapper but defined it's style as .wrapper.
Either rename the class of the div to wrapper or change the class name in css from wrapper to column.

```
<div class="wrapper">...</div>
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/981f2xL7/)

Comment: It helped but not 100%. Now the columns starts from the middle of the webpage. And I see only 1 column and half of the second one

Comment: I have updated the answer with a fiddle and you can see it is working as expected. The issue must be with other part of your css, that is not given here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `column` div.

Try this:

```
<style>
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: red;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);   
 grid-gap: 10px;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}
.one {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1  ;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.two {
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: yellow;
   grid-column: 2 ;
   grid-row: 1 ;
}
.three {
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: violet;
   grid-column: 3;
   grid-row: 1;
 }
.four {
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: aqua;
   grid-column: 4;
   grid-row: 1;
 }
 }
 </style>

   <div class='wrapper'>

 <div class="one" style="background-color:#aaa;">
   <h2>Column 1</h2>
   <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
 </div>
 <div class="three" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="four" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
   </div>
```